# TYPO3 Extbase: persisting domain model with datetime property

Tags: validation, datetime, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I am really stuck here (maybe the sickness is not helping...).

**Setting:**
- typo3 6.2 with according extbase and fluid
- checked about 20 blog entries, the official docu, and a few code snippets I found
- Senior on developing TYPO3, but relatively new to extbase/fluid

**Goal:**
As many of you, I try to realize a form in the frontend to create a new object. This object contains some datetime properties.

**Symptoms:**
- I can create an object in the backend and correctly output it with fluid creating lists and having some fun with it, no problem so far.
- When filling out the form I get the all known FlashErrorMessage "An error occurred while trying to call"
- After styling the form fields that give an error (used the f3-form-error css-class) I could determine the input fields of the datetime properties as the bad guys.

tca excerpt:

```
'startdate' => array(
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:ngibmembers/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:paymentperiod.startdate',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'input',
        'size' => 30,
        'eval' => 'date',
    ),
),
'stopdate' => array(
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:ngibmembers/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:paymentperiod.stopdate',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'input',
        'size' => 30,
        'eval' => 'date',
    ),
),
```

then here the domain model part:

```
/**
 * startdate
 *
 * @var \DateTime
 * @validate DateTime
 */
protected $startdate;

/**
 * stopdate
 *
 * @var \DateTime
 * @validate DateTime
 */
protected $stopdate;

/**
 * Get startdate
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
 public function getStartdate(){
     return $this->startdate;
 }

 /**
  * Set startdate
  *
  * @param \DateTime $startdate
  * @return Paymentperiod
  */
  public function setStartdate($startdate){
      $this->startdate = $startdate;
      return $this;
  }

/**
 * Get stopdate
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
 public function getStopdate(){
     return $this->stopdate;
 }

/**
 * Set stopdate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $stopdate
 * @return Paymentperiod
 */
 public function setStopdate($stopdate){
     $this->stopdate = $stopdate;
     return $this;
 }
```

the Actions

```
/**
 * convert date properties
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function initializeAction(){
$dateFormat = 'dd.mm.yyyy';
if (isset($this->arguments['paymentperiod'])) {
    $this->arguments['paymentperiod']
        ->getPropertyMappingConfiguration()
        ->forProperty('startdate')
        ->setTypeConverterOption(
            'TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\TypeConverter\DateTimeConverter',
            \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\TypeConverter\DateTimeConverter::CONFIGURATION_DATE_FORMAT,
            $dateFormat);
}
if (isset($this->arguments['paymentperiod'])) {
    $this->arguments['paymentperiod']
        ->getPropertyMappingConfiguration()
        ->forProperty('stopdate')
        ->setTypeConverterOption(
            'TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\TypeConverter\DateTimeConverter',
            \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\TypeConverter\DateTimeConverter::CONFIGURATION_DATE_FORMAT,
            $dateFormat);
}
}

/**
 * action new
 *
 * @param \NGiB\Ngibmembers\Domain\Model\Paymentperiod $paymentperiod
 * @ignorevalidation $paymentperiod
 * @return void
 */
public function newAction(\NGiB\Ngibmembers\Domain\Model\Paymentperiod $paymentperiod = NULL) {
    $this->view->assign('paymentperiod',$paymentperiod);
    $this->view->assign('settings',$this->settings);
}

/**
 * action create
 *
 * @param \NGiB\Ngibmembers\Domain\Model\Paymentperiod $paymentperiod
 * @return void
 */
public function createAction(Paymentperiod $paymentperiod) {
    $this->paymentRepository->add($paymentperiod);
    $this->redirect('new');
}
```

and then the snippets from the fluid template:

```
<f:form action="create" object="{paymentperiod}" class="form-horizontal" name="paymentperiod">

<f:form.textfield
    id="paymentperiod_field_startdate"
    property="startdate"
    class="form-control" />
```

so, where is my problem????

Many thanks for everyone who helps.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

ok, found the problem:

so the bootstrap datepicker I chose needs 'dd.mm.yyyy' in the dateformat to give a correct central european formatted date.

After some more debugging and reading, I finally found out, that the PHP DateTime class uses 'd.m.Y' to resolve the same format.

changing the dateFormat in the initializeAction of the controller solved the validation problem.

I definitely need to get a better datepicker library there :S

Answer (score 0):

You can set the format in a own input field:

```
<f:form.textfield value="{review.datumAenderung->f:format.date(format:'Y.m.d')}" class="form-control"  name="review[datumAenderung][date]" />
<f:form.textfield class="form-control" name="review[datumAenderung][dateFormat]" value="Y.m.d" />
```