# Convert data in TYPO3 fluid form

Tags: typo3

I need yours help. I have follow form:

```
{namespace femanager=In2code\Femanager\ViewHelpers}
<div class="femanager_fieldset femanager_membershipend control-group">
    <label for="femanager_field_membershipend" class="control-label">
        <f:translate key="tx_feusersplus_domain_model_user.membershipend" default="Expiration date of the membership"/>
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <femanager:form.textfield
                disabled="true"
                id="femanager_field_membershipend"
                property="membershipend"
                class="input-block-level"
                additionalAttributes="{femanager:Validation.FormValidationData(settings:settings,fieldName:'membershipend')}"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

And it get date in the next format - 1493942400. How I can make good look for date ? Thank you for advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property seems to be declared as integer (unix timestamp) in the model.

You can change the field to the following:

```
<femanager:form.textfield
            disabled="true"
            id="femanager_field_membershipend"
            property="membershipend"
            class="input-block-level" value="{yourModel.membershipend-> f:format.date(format: 'd.m.Y')}"
            additionalAttributes="{femanager:Validation.FormValidationData(settings:settings,fieldName:'membershipend')}"
    />
```

This will format the property to a readable Date. But after that you will get problems saving the property correctly. If the property is really an integer, you need to write a converter for converting the date to an unix timestamp. It [must work like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951582/typo3-extbase-persisting-domain-model-with-datetime-property) just in the reverse and I think TYPO3 does not have the correct converter for your needs out of the box.

I recommend you to change your property to DateTime (including the database field). Then you can use the DateTimeConverter of TYPO3 to save the data correctly.

**EDIT:** In your case the field is disabled="true" which should mean that the data will not become submitted. In that case you should not get problems with converting after submitting the form.

Comment: I tried value="{User.membershipend->f:format.date(format: 'd.m.Y')}" but it show nothing ((  if I use just  value="{User.membershipend} it return just integer as early. If I try value="{User555.membershipend} it return integer value too, but model User555 does't exist! May be I should set model with namespace or something like that ?

Comment: I tried <f:debug>{User}</f:debug>  and it return NULL. Can you help me, please )

Comment: Is the formfield above inside a FLUID partial file? Then you have to pass your model from your main form-template to the partials using `<f:render partial="YourPartialWhatever" arguments="{yourModel: yourModel}" />`. If you dont know how the variable is named in your template, take a look at your `<f:form object="{yourModel}" />` tag.

Comment: Thank you! All work! Just not User, user is rigth! ) Not big letter u ))